# Get live output from terminal window through PHP 7

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get a live output (when a line appears in the window, it should appear on the server as well) of a terminal window on Ubuntu 16.04. I have various needs for this to work. I am first off trying to get 'sudo apt-get update' to be executed by an HTML button and the terminal output to be received live in the client browser... I've trying using flush() and what-not but cannot seem to get it to work... Any PHP specialists willing to help out here? Thank you!

Here is what I currently have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Censored</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    echo
    "<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='command' value='Network Properties' />
    </form>";

    if(isset($_POST['command']))
    {
        $cmd= shell_exec('ifconfig -a');
        echo '<pre>$cmd</pre>';
    }

    echo
    "<form action='' method='post'>
    <input type='submit' name='update' value='apt-get update' />
    </form>";

    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
          echo '<pre>';
          flush();
            $output = system('sudo apt-get update');
          echo '</pre>';
    }
    ?>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice:

1. If you want to see the result in real time, turn off output buffering first.

[Detailed instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882383/how-to-disable-output-buffering-in-php)

2. **Most important**:  `shell_exec` won't return anything before it finished. You have to use an alternative method, to get the output in real time.

[Related Instruction 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370628/php-shell-exec-with-realtime-updating)
 [Related Instruction 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107147/php-reading-shell-exec-live-output)